# Account with Event tagging of Yes or No in SOQL

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, event, wrapper-class, person-accounts

My objective for this query is to show all of his/her accounts with tag of With Call Event (Yes & No). Meaning, Fields = "Branch", "With Call Event?"

I tried below class but nothing is showing up on the event object.

```
  @AuraEnabled 
        public static List<Account> fetchAccounts(){
            Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            
            //AccountTeamMember Query
            List<AccountTeamMember> members = [
                SELECT
                    Id,
                    AccountId
                FROM
                    AccountTeamMember
                WHERE
                    UserId = :userId];
            
            //Get IDs for All Accounts in ATM
            Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(AccountTeamMember member : members) {
                accountIds.add(member.AccountId);
            }
            
            //Query the Accounts
            List<Account> acc = [
                SELECT
                    Id,
                    Name,
                    Branch_Code__c,
                    Branch_Name__c,
                    (SELECT Id, WhatId, Count__c FROM Events WHERE Type='Call')
                FROM
                    Account
                WHERE
                    Id IN :accountIds
                    OR OwnerId = :userId];
                //];
            
            return acc;
        }
```

Comment: This sounds like troubleshooting 101. Have you checked there are calls associated with the accounts? have you tried running this in execute anonymous?  Is the class with sharing or without sharing? (i.e. is it a security/sharing issue)

Comment: Yes, sorry I am still newbie here in lightning development. Yes, I tried creating a call event associated to a specific branch. And also tried to query in workbench but no single data on the event field is showing up.

Comment: What do you mean by a call event?  When troubleshooting, you need to isolate your variables.   e..g is the WHERE clause causing an issue? if you remove it and events show up, you know it's a problem with your where clause. is the lightning component causing an issue?  try running it in execute anonymous to remove the LWC as the issue.  You didn't answer the question about the with/without sharing.  If you have a private model, that could be the problem. try setting it to without sharing to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Opps sorry, call event meaning workplan. Created a Call Event type in Calendar. And yes with sharing.

Comment: your query will locate accounts with or without Events of Type='Call'. So, you'll need to filter out from `acc` those with an empty related list of Events.